# Sort based on 2 attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I'm trying to sort numbers in lexicographical (reverse) order and from shortest to longest number. 
So for example the numbers `9989, 989, 9` should be rearanged as `9, 9989, 989`.

I'm trying this code:

```
a.sort(key=lambda x:([x[i] for i in range(len(x))],len(x)), reverse=True)
```

but it only does a right job when the numbers have the same length. How should I fix it so that shorter numbers would come before longer numbers (i.e., 9 before 99)?

Comment: Why does 9989 come before 989?

Comment: because their first integer is 9 we move to check the second integer which is 9 and 8 respectively so 9989 is before 989 (pay attention to the fact that i stated reverse=True)

Comment: So by your description, 999 will come before 8?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye exactly

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
a = ['9989', '989', '999', '8', '9'] 
max_a = len(max(a, key=len))  
sorted(a, key=lambda x: x + 'a'*(max_a - len(x)), reverse=True)
# ['9', '999', '9989', '989', '8']
```

Comment: I had to change sorted(a,...) to sorted(sorted(a),...) because it would fail for ['999', '9'] as '9' comes after '999' and we compare '999' with '999' (for '9'+'9'*2).

Comment: Nifty solution, but sorting twice to handle an edge case isn't very nice.

Comment: Ok, fixed that. We can fill strings with e.g. 'a' instead of '9' because 'a'>'9'. So we don't need to sort twice.

Answer (score 1):

You can hardly write a **meaningful** *key* function in Python 3 for this type of sorting without resorting to a comparator function and then using [`functools.comp_to_key`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key) to make it into a key function.

Check which of the items is larger up to their minimum length (using `zip` to iterate on both stops at min length), if both are same, check their lengths:

```
from functools import cmp_to_key

def comparator(x, y):
   if x == y: return 0
   for i, j in zip(x, y):
      if i != j:
         return int(j)-int(i) # the reversal is done here
   return 1 if len(x) > len(y) else -1


t = '9989', '989', '9'
print(sorted(t, key=cmp_to_key(comparator)))
# ['9', '9989', '989']

t = '888', '9989', '989', '9', '8'
print(sorted(t, key=cmp_to_key(comparator)))
# ['9', '9989', '989', '8', '888']
```

The sort function is quite readable, does not process further when the items are equal, and with `zip`, stops on the min length; **adaptive**.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with, similar idea to [@Andyk's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2945357/andyk) but avoiding a double sort and using `int` input. It requires importing `math.inf` to handle, for example, `[9989, 989, 999, 9, 99]`.

```
from math import inf
from functools import partial

a = [9989, 989, 9]

def sort_algo(x, k):
    x_str = list(str(x))
    return list(map(int, x_str)) + [inf]*(k-len(x_str))

n = max(map(len, map(str, a)))
sorter = partial(sort_algo, k=n)
a.sort(key=sorter, reverse=True)

print(a)

[9, 9989, 989]
```